# After installing kubernetes add-on heapster take login time to load dashboard pod & node status page

Tags: kubernetes

After installing kubernetes add-on it take login time to load dashboard pod & node status page. during this time I didn't see any CPU or Memory usage high on my nodes.

```
deploy/kube-config/influxdb/grafana.yaml
deploy/kube-config/influxdb/heapster.yaml
deploy/kube-config/influxdb/influxdb.yaml
```

Here are running pods and services.

```
[root@master01 heapster]#  kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default-http-backend   10.108.228.89    <none>        80/TCP          9h
heapster               10.100.200.252   <none>        80/TCP          3h
kube-dns               10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   14d
kubernetes-dashboard   10.96.25.153     <nodes>       80:31511/TCP    8d
monitoring-grafana     10.102.103.4     <none>        80/TCP          3h
monitoring-influxdb    10.101.51.148    <none>        8086/TCP        3h
[root@master01 heapster]#  kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-http-backend-2198840601-99gk4   1/1       Running   1          5h
etcd-master01                           1/1       Running   14         11d
heapster-1428305041-hnw3k               1/1       Running   1          3h
kube-apiserver-master01                 1/1       Running   31         14d
kube-controller-manager-master01        1/1       Running   27         14d
kube-dns-3913472980-5kpg2               3/3       Running   568        14d
kube-flannel-ds-66x5q                   2/2       Running   34         10d
kube-flannel-ds-6ls9n                   2/2       Running   39         10d
kube-flannel-ds-htggq                   2/2       Running   41         10d
kube-proxy-0cp1q                        1/1       Running   28         14d
kube-proxy-98p5n                        1/1       Running   20         14d
kube-proxy-rgjw2                        1/1       Running   22         14d
kube-scheduler-master01                 1/1       Running   27         14d
kubernetes-dashboard-3858955849-srhqf   1/1       Running   21         7d
monitoring-grafana-3975459543-r9v50     1/1       Running   1          3h
monitoring-influxdb-3480804314-t6nt7    1/1       Running   1          3h
```

I have restated the all three nodes still it takes long time to load pod status page.

this page took 4.2 min. to load http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/api/v1/pod/default?itemsPerPage=10&page=1

If I remove below three apps. its loading normal.

Any tips to debug this issue?
[image]
thanks
SR